# React, Mobx, Firebase conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, mobx

i have a problem with a basic conditional rendering.
basically i have this Store:

```
import { ObservableMap, observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
import fb from '../firebase';

class ProductStore {
  @observable products = [];

  constructor() {
    fb.products.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.products = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        this.products.push({
          id: child.key,
          ...child.val()
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @action addProduct = (product) => {
    fb.products.push(product);
  }

  @action removeProduct = (product) => {
    fb.products.child(product.id).set({});
  }

  @computed get totalProducts() {
    return this.products.length;
  }


}

const store = new ProductStore();
export default store ;
```

I'm trying to render a message if i don't have any product stored on firebase, and the loading... message, if i'm getting the data from firebase, so i'm doing this now:

```
const ProductList = (props) => {

  const renderView = () => {
    if(props.products.length){
      return props.products.map((product,index) => <Product key={index} product={product} removeProduct={props.removeProduct}/>);
    }else{
      return <p>Loading...</p>
    }
  }

    return (
      <div className="product-list">
        {console.log(props.products)}
        {renderView()}
      </div>  
    )
}
```

how can i print the message "products not found" if i don't have any data on firebase? cause in the beginning i initialize the products observable to an array, then react show the loading message and after that it loads in the data, but then if i remove all the data on firebase of course it show the loading message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extend your `ProductStore` with a `isLoading` field:

```
class ProductStore {
  @observable products = [];
  @observable isLoading = true;

  constructor() {
    fb.products.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const products = [];

      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        products.push({
          id: child.key,
          ...child.val()
        });
      });

     this.products.replace(products);
     this.isLoading = false;
    }, (error) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @action addProduct = (product) => {
    fb.products.push(product);
  }

  @action removeProduct = (product) => {
    fb.products.child(product.id).set({});
  }

  @computed get totalProducts() {
    return this.products.length;
  }
}
```

And use this in conjunction with `products.length` in your view:

```
const ProductList = ({ isLoading, products }) => {
  let result;

  if (isLoading) {
    result = <p>Loading...</p>;
  } else if (products.length === 0) {
    result = <p>Products not found</p>;
  } else {
    result = products.map((product, index) => <Product key={index} product={product} removeProduct={props.removeProduct}/>);
  }

  return (
    <div className="product-list">
      {result}
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! tomorrow i'll try it at work! :) one question, you are using replace to return a new array right? to make it immutable?

Comment: @LucaBaxter Great! I'm using the MobX array [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) method in order to replace the content of the array, and not overwrite the observable array reference with an ordinary array. Subtle bugs can be introduced that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use firestore, an alternative is the Firestorter library: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/firestorter, which has 'isLoading', 'isActive' and 'ready' that you can utilise.

You probably won't want to re-engineer to do this, but others might find it interesting.